# No session No cookies?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

i have problem for access user information without using session and without using cookies.
How can i manage user information without session and without cookies??
Please help

Comment: You can't. Why do you want to?

Comment: You could use http basic authentication and track everything by the username in play. That doesn't use cookies or sessions, but can simulate sessions by tying everything to the username, rather than random-ish session ID+cookie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you are talking about web browsers and HTTP: You can't.

HTTP is a **stateless** protocol. To overload it with server-side state requires some means of uniquely identifying the requestor. And cookies are the only way web browsers have of maintaining client-side state.

[edited to note]I should point out, however, that one could conceivable embed a limited amount of state data in the URI proper, as part of the *query* or *fragment* portions of the URI. It's limited because most (every?) implementation imposes some sort of limit on the maximum length of a URI. Further, your web app will need to ensure that the state data is propagated from URL to URL properly. And it should be encrypted for security, lest URI-twiddling allows your site to be cracked.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a MySQL Database to store user information. Unfortunately though, without using session variables you'll have to either pass the user's credentials in a url variable like ?username=dave password=cat (DO NOT EVER DO THIS PLEASE) or you'll just have to learn some things about security and do things the right way (PREFERRED).

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a needless requirement<sup>Caveat Below</sup>, but I'll take a shot.

When the user logs in, issue them a security token. Store that token in the database. The token should contain an arbitrary value (e.g. a hex encoded GUID), **not** a name or password. The database also stores the relationship between the token and an actual user ID. The token should have an expiration date.

Pass the token along with every request as part of the URL (ASP.Net does this for cookieless sessions). Since you don't want to use session state, you have to store any information related to the user somewhere else, probably a database. Every URL on every page will need to have the token.

You can also leverage [local storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Storage) in the web browser for non-security information.

There **are** situations where session is impractical in ASP.Net, even for very lightweight objects. This is because of how session access is serialized; let's say you have a dashboard page full of widgets making requests to a WCF endpoint that needs to be aware of session-related information. If that endpoint uses session state, performance will suffer as each request will execute serially.

> ...if two concurrent requests are made for the same session (by using
>   the same SessionID value), the first request gets exclusive access to
>   the session information. The second request executes only after the
>   first request is finished.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 0):

A hidden input on each page can do this, but you'll be stuck using POST for everything rather than GET. This is highly unrecommended.